# I am trying to instantiate a map with basics but it throws an error?

Tags: javascript, html, here-api

I followed the directions in the here maps and trying to instantiate a map. It throws the following error.

> "InvalidArgumentError: H.Map (Argument #0 null)"

My code is as below :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />

<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"
      type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"
      type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
      'apikey': 'Entered the right api key'
    });
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

//Instantiate (and display) a map object:
var map = new H.Map(
 document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
 defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
 {
   zoom: 10,
   center: { lat: 52.5, lng: 13.4 }
 });

    </script>

<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id='mapContainer'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The timing is wrong, the element you're trying to refer doesn't exist.

Comment: place your js code just before the closing body tag.

Comment: what do you mean i refered it from here maps website itself  [link](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics/get-started.html) @Teemu

Comment: Did that too @KK

Comment: I mean that "_the element you're trying to refer doesn't exist_". You're trying get a reference to `#mapContainer`, but that element does not exist at the time you're trying to refer it. The head section is guaranteed to be parsed first, and all the script being executed, before browser starts parsing the body section. Hence the div you're trying to refer, is not even in a margarine box yet.

Comment: Thanks@Teemu Understood where i did wrong

Answer (score 0):

Problem is timing. You are trying to init something and can be that the apropriate js libs are not loaded to this moment.. easest solution is to put your code inside of document.ready from JQuery for example:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var platform = new H.service.Platform({
    'apikey': 'Entered the right api key'
  });
  var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

  //Instantiate (and display) a map object:
  var map = new H.Map(
  document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
  defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
  {
    zoom: 10,
    center: { lat: 52.5, lng: 13.4 }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

please correct your code define the `<div style="width: 640px; height: 480px" id='mapContainer'></div>` before you start using in the script tag.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"
  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"
  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>  

<body>
<div style="width: 640px; height: 480px" id='mapContainer'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
      'apikey': '{}'
    });
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

//Instantiate (and display) a map object:
var map = new H.Map(
 document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
 defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
 {
   zoom: 10,
   center: { lat: 52.5, lng: 13.4 }
 });

    </script>

   </body>  
 </html>
```